# Point subdomain to root drupal install

Tags: domain-access

I have been tasked to flush out the content on a drupal site that utilizes the domain access module for multiple subdomains under one DB.

- I have gone to structure->domains  and added all the domains but when I try to visit them I get server not found.
- I have found that I need to direct the DNS to each url? I am still a little unsure of how this works. Is there a way to do this without accessing the host like through the .htaccess file or settings.php or httpconfig? I need to **"configure all domains to the primary VirtualHost's ServerAlias, or else point all relevant DocumentRoots to my single installation of Drupal."**

Can someone please help me get these last two subdomains pointed to the root install of drupal so the site actually shows up? Is this possible to do without editting the httpd.config file as I don't have access to the server files.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The Domain Access module has quite [thorough documentation](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/domain).

For your specific issue, you want the [Before installing section](http://drupal.org/node/1096954), which covers the necessary Apache configuration. In short, you're right that you want to configure all domains to point at a single docroot--once that is set up, Domain Access will properly handle which content is available on specific domains.